# Excel convert MMM DD, YYYY to string

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to convert a date string into a date format the strings look like this

Nov 28, 2005 12:00 AM

and i would like them in the format DD/MM/YYYY i have been trying to find a solution online by using the =DATEVALUE() formulae however keep getting a #VALUE error.

starting to pull my hair out now, so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Do you get an error if you do `=YEAR(A1)` or whatever your cell is?

Answer (score 1):

there's a function `TEXT` that will allow you to get the date in the format you choose.

For your questions `TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")` will give you the format you desire